# Prevent inconsistent queuing of onSensorChanged()

Tags: android, multithreading, wear-os, sensormanager

So I have been struggling with this challenge for a while now, exploring different possibilities and narrowing down where the 'queuing' happens. Let me first explain what I am trying to do.

**What do I want to do?**
I am writing an Android app (running on Google Pixel) with a Wearable service (running on a Sony Smartwatch 3) to retrieve sensor data from the smartwatch as fast as possible, logging the result as Verbose. This currently happens at around 150Hz, data from the TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR. This data is send over a channel (outputstream) using a [PrintWriter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and retreived by the phone on the same channel (inputstream) using a [BufferReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html). I am using the ChannelApi, as the DataApi ensures delivery, yet my aim is to deliver sensor data as fast as possible to real-time, where data loss is of less importance. I am currently reading the ADB on my laptop to use this in another application.

**What is the issue / challenge?**
After getting the system time at several stages in my program I discovered that that the queuing of data was not the fault of the ADB connection, nor the input or outputstream nor the printwriter. It seems that the function `onSensorChanged()` is not called instantly as the `sensorEvent` happens. To illustrate, below are the times send as data, for each `onSensorChanged()` event, with the sensorListener set to SENSOR_DELAY_GAME (but also accounts for SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST.

- 1st row: `System.currentTimeMillis()` on the watch when `onSensorChanged()` is called
- 2nd row: the `event.timestamp` (divided by 1000000 to go from nano to milli seconds) from the `sensorEvent`

This gives an overview of a few sensor readings:

```
1479407287638;    687629;
1479407287638;    687649;
1479407287681;    687669;
1479407287681;    687689;
1479407287718;    687709;
1479407287718;    687729;
1479407287768;    687749;
1479407287768;    687769;
1479407287810;    687789;
1479407287811;    687809;
```

If you look at the differences between the times you get:

```
-      -
 0;    20
49;    20
 0;    20
37;    20
 0;    20
50;    20
 0;    20
42;    20
 1;    20
```

As you can see, the `sensorTimestamp` indicates there are readings every 20ms. However, the `onSensorChanged()` is not called at the same intervals, or at least consistency. To point out, even on high speeds the Channel and its input- and outputwriter are able to keep up with the amount of bytes/messages, even on longer periods or time.

**What have I tried?**

I tried to remove all tasks from `onSensorChanged`

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    final int accuracy = event.accuracy;
    final long timestamp = event.timestamp;
    final float[] values = event.values;
    final String sensorName = event.sensor.getStringType();

    if (data_transfer) {                        // if interaction is initiated
        printWriter.println(message);
    }
}
```

I tried to remove all tasks from `onSensorChanged` and executed them elsewhere in an initiated thread

```
if (data_transfer) {                        // if interaction is initiated
    new Thread(new convertAndSend(sensorName,timestamp,accuracy,values)).run();
}
```

At first I wrote the wearable app as an activity, but I also converted it to a service (running in the background)

```
public class SensorService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {
...
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        client.sendSensorData(event.sensor.getType(), event.accuracy, event.timestamp/1000000, event.values); //client takes care of outputstream
    }
}
```

Lastly, I thought about implemeting the `SensorEventListener` in a seperate thread (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681870/android-which-thread-calls-onsensorchanged) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286815/sensoreventlistener-in-separate-thread) Stackoverflow Q&A, so it would not be influenced by the Activity or Service thread. However, this also showed the same issue / challenge as mentioned before.

```
public class SensorListenerThread implements Runnable {

    private static final String TAG = "SensorService";
    private final static int SENS_ROTATION_VECTOR = Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR;

    SensorManager mSensorManager;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d( "RunTag", Thread.currentThread().getName() ); // To display thread

        mSensorManager = ((SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));

        Looper.prepare();
        Handler handler = new Handler(){
            // process incoming messages here??
        };
        Sensor rotationVectorSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(SENS_ROTATION_VECTOR);
        MySensorListener msl = new MySensorListener();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(msl, rotationVectorSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, handler);

        Looper.loop();
    }

    private class MySensorListener implements SensorEventListener {
        public void onAccuracyChanged (Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            Log.d( "ListenerTag", Thread.currentThread().getName() ); // To display thread
        }
    }

}
```

**Help!**
My understanding is that the `onSensorChanged` event is called however not at the same times as the timestamp of the sensor seems to indicate. The speed and using the channel work very well, however I cannot seem to get a workaround this issue. I have a plan B in my mind: I can use the sensor timestamp to calculate/adjust the program I am running on my laptop. However, I prefer only to adjust for the delay in communication (from sensor --> laptop application, which could be a variable that is changed every now and then) and not also adjust for the inconsistency in communication (differences in printing the values, which need to be calculated for each reading).

I hope this long (sorry!) story makes sense and someone can help me or point me in the correct direction!

Comment: You might want to check the use of [Worker threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) to handle more complex interactions. As mentioned in the given documentation, you might consider using a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in your worker thread, to process messages delivered from the UI thread. Perhaps the best solution, is to extend the [AsyncTask class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which simplifies the execution of worker thread tasks that need to interact with the UI.

Comment: hi @Teyam, I have implemented a worker thread only to receive the onSensorchanged() messages. It does not interfere with the UI thread anymore. However, also in this case the messages are received with consistent time in between. I was hoping it was possible to construct the code in such a way that the time between a sensor message (the timestamp) and receiving the message (onSensorChanged) could be consistent. I now currently have to look at the sensor timestamps and calculate the corresponding time of the occurance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, it might not be possible to rely on a consistent call of onSensorChanged(). I am therefore using the timestamps rather than the time of onSensorChanged. I would advice others to do the same!