# Getting the actual orientation of the phone

Tags: java, android, orientation

I need to determine the actual orientation of the phone which is running my app and I can't find any way to do it. I have found the "getRequestedOrientation" function but it only retrieves the orientation set by the "setRequestedOrientation" function.

In my app, I let the phone choose the orientation according to it's physical orientation. And I have some customizing to do depending on the result.

How can I do?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [getRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

According to these two questions:

- [Check orientation on Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)
- [How can I get the current screen orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663665/how-can-i-get-the-current-screen-orientation)

you can use:

`Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`

According to the comment on the second question, however, this value returns only landscape
or portrait.  If you need reverse orientation as well, I would suggest querying the accelerometer
values to detect the difference.  However, I'm not familiar with Android and 
accelerometers enough to suggest how to do so exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Its really to get the current orientation.

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
int orientation = display.getOrientation();
```

Comment: Simpler yet... getResources().getConfiguration().orientation

Comment: This answer put me on the way but the "getSystemService" returned a null handle. I have used "getWindowManager" instead and it works.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone), [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819626/android-phone-orientation-overview-including-compass) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript) stackoverflow question. They all address how to get the Android phone orientation and the second one includes a detailed explanation of how the Android compass and orientation system works.