# Check a screen orientation when it's fixed by manifest file

Tags: android, camera

I have an camera activity in my app, where user can make a photo. For some reasons it's fixed to landscape mode(by the screenOrientation in manifest). All works perfectly but I need to know - what screen mode on picture? User can rotate device and try to make a photo in portrait mode.

I've tried to use getRotation method but it returnes only 0 degrees, cause i'm set to portrait screenOrientation.

I want to ask - is there some ways to solve this problem?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the orientation sensor, ain't as difficult as you might think.

http://www.workingfromhere.com/blog/2009/03/30/orientation-sensor-tips-in-android/

[Android phone orientation overview including compass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819626/android-phone-orientation-overview-including-compass)