# Android sensors to control game

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, android-sdk-2.1

I'm trying to setup my android game to use android sensors for controlling the game.

When the phone is tilted forwards slightly, I want the thrusters to fire.

And tilting the phone left or right rotates it in the rescpetive direction.

At the moment, I'm using TYPE_ORIENTATION as follows:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(mMode == STATE_RUNNING) {    

            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {

                //rotation
                float pitch = event.values[2]; // pitch
                if(pitch <= 15 & pitch >= -15) {
                    mRotating = 0;
                } else if(pitch < -15) {
                    mRotating += 1;
                } else if(pitch > 15) {
                    mRotating -= 1;
                }

                //thrust by tilting forward!
                if(event.values[0] > 0) {
                    thrusterFiring = true;
                } else {
                    thrusterFiring = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I'm not sure if this is quite right? Additionally, you have to filt the phone quite a bit forwards in order for the thrusters to fire - I'd like it so you only need to tilt a little!

Any help appreciated!

Comment: i think you should use accelerometer

Comment: You might find this useful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819626/android-phone-orientation-overview-including-compass